# Create repeated fade-out effect by using className Method and setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, setinterval

Dears,

I have an assignment that is to create a repeated fade-out effect by using setInterval and using the DOM className method, below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.mystyle {
    background-color: coral;
    padding: 16px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
    }
</style>

<body>

   <div id="myDIV"></div>

   <p>Click the button to set a class for myDIV:</p>

   <button onclick="setInterval()">Try it</button>

   <script>
    setInterval(change, 2000)

    function change() {
              function subchange1(){
                  document.getElementById("myDIV").className = "mystyle";
                   };
              function subchange2(){
              document.getElementById("myDIV").className = "";
                  };
                  }
            </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

However, it shows no change at all, could you tell me where i get wrong and how to correct it?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You've used `setInterval()` as a user defined function. It needs two arguments one is **callback function** and other is time interval. You should've used and remove the `setInterval` in JS.

```
<button onclick="setInterval(change, 2000)">Try it</button>
```

2. In `change()` function you just declared the functions. You didn't call them back. It will not give you expected output even if you call them.
3. For your code to work you need to check if `myDiv` has class `.mystyle`. For that you'll need to use `if-else` statements.

---

**Here's a Working code :-**

```js
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");

function change() {
  if (myDiv.className === "mystyle") {
    myDiv.className = "";
  } else {
    myDiv.className = "mystyle";
  }
}

function startAnimation() {
  setInterval(change, 2000);
};
```

```css
#myDIV {
  background-color: #1a8cff;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.mystyle {
  background-color: coral;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV"></div>

<p>Click the button to set a class for myDIV:</p>

<button onclick="startAnimation()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Was writing the same thing midway and loaded this answer, +1

Comment: I would refrain using arrow functions in a begginer assignment where there is already cofusion with how to use the traditional function notation.

Comment: You might also want to put everything together in script and style tag to avoid further mistakes like the missing head tag above.

Comment: Many thanks.  Yes, I had tried your code, excellent!  However, but what's wrong in my code, you see in my css, there is no class for the element with ID "myDIV", so my idea is to add a class to this element so that fade out effect can be created, then i remove it by adding another new class "", where this logic get wrong?  Please instruct...Thanks

Comment: Relevant information for handling homework questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Shrey Thanks your answer, after few research, I release the fail in my first codes is because of the async nature of the code.  To solve this issue, I have further modified my codes by using setTimeout, feel free to comment to my answer i just post, Thanks very much!

Comment: @FK  Thanks your comment and suggestion, after few research, I release the fail in my first codes is because of the async nature of the code. To solve this issue, I have further modified my codes by using setTimeout, feel free to comment to my answer i just post, Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an assignment that you have to complete, I will only list the issue I notice and let you fix them as an exercise.

1. You have a `<style>` tag directly inside the `<html>`. You should have that style inside of a `<head>` element.
2. Code functions called inside of the `<script>` tag are executed directly and immediately. You are calling `setInterval(change, 2000)` directly so there is no need to to add it to the `<button>` tag. If you want the repeated action to only start when you press the button, you need to call setInterval, this line `setInterval(change, 2000)`, inside of another function, like `start` for example. Then you add `start` to  onclick like this: `onclick="start()"`.
3. The `change` function has 2 function declarations in it but no function calls. This means that the two functions inside of it, `subchange1` and `subchange2` are never called. To use a function you need to call it. You should move those two functions outside, after the `change` function, and then you can call them by using `subchange1()` and `subchange2()`.

That will fix your code issues but don't have correct logic to implement the function requirements. You can search for `class toggle function` and find different ways of doing it. I suggest in going with the one that better matches what you have already learned.

This looks like a medium to advanced assignment. The best way to solve these will be to start simple and test your code as you progess. It will be very dificult to write everything and test. I highly suggest you write a simple function call, like `alert(7)`, and then add it to the button, test the button,   then add it to a function, test the function with the button, then use it with `setInterval`. This will make sure you have things working before you add more complexity.

Good luck with you assignment :)

Comment: How did you know that this is homework?

Comment: This is a basic programming question that starts with "I have an assignment".

Comment: I just read the code! Skipped the question!

Comment: Many thanks for your educate, i will digest what you mention above and try again and again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After few research,  i found that it is highly the cause of the async nature of the codes of Javascript, i found using setTimeout can overcome this issue and my code is below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
 .mystyle {
   background-color: coral;
   padding: 16px;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 1s linear;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="myDIV" >
 <p>I am myDIV.</p>
 </div>
 <p>Click the button to set a class for myDIV:</p>
 <button onclick="change()">Try it</button>

 <script>
 function change(){
 let abc = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 abc.className = "mystyle";
 setTimeout(function() {abc.className = "";}, 1000);
 setTimeout(change, 2000);
 };
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```